# Where does this particular series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I have the following series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{x^{b+n}}{b+n}.$$

The series seems to converge in the open interval $(0,1)$. But can you tell to which function it converges?

Please note that here $b$ is any positive real number less than $1$ and $x$ lies in the open interval $(0,1)$ and $n$ belongs to the set of non-negative integers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{b-1+n}=\frac{x^{b-1}}{x+1}$$ so that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{b+n}}{b+n}=\int_0^x\frac{t^b}{t+1}dx.$$

This is an incomplete Beta integral.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer.